# Can SmartSVN be used as a command-line tool?

Tags: svn, scripting, smartsvn

I would like to write a script that checks out stuff from a repository every couple of hours, and I'd like to know if I could use SmartSVN from the command line to do it. If SmartSVN can't be used from the command line, what subversion client could I use? Please recommend one that supports authentication as well ( I'm hoping all of them know how to do that, but you never know ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know about SmartSVN. Using the official [Subversion binaries](http://subversion.tigris.org/) will give you command-line access.

Comment: SVN also has bindings for a number of scripting languages such as Python and Perl, if you want to go that route.

Comment: @Ferruccio: Yes, that will be a better route.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to have a Java-based solution, give [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com) a try.

Comment: For those that are already using SmartSVN, it appears that it was built on top of SVNKit.  Version 7 contains a batch script withing %SmartSVNHome%\lib directory, that calls jsvn.jar.  I'm not sure if all the functionality (help for some commands is missing) but I was able to run tradition svn cli calls from this jar.

Answer (score 1):

SmartSVN has no command line tool, means you can not execute SVN commands if only SmartSVN is installed on your OS.

If you would like to have SVN command line, you have to install some official binaries. [Here](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) you can find some according to your OS.